Is it possible to pass a variable within a text field or rich text in strapi ? And when fetched api it repalce the variable with value
I want pass a variable in fields of strapi content.
like if I have field title I want to set value like "This is a my {variable} title"
For another field "This is my {variable} title2"
I want to replace these variables with a value from either another field value of strapi or env when fetched api.
I have multiple single types in strapi like Home, About, Contact. I want to pass a common variable or field value within another field like-
In Home I have field "section1" i want to set value like "We are present for {years} in industry".
In About I have field "about_content" i want to set value like "Some other text. We have {years} + experience"
When I fetch api I want result for home.section1 ="We are present for 14 in industry"
about.about_content = "Some other text. We have 14 + experience"
Is there any ways to implement this ?
